# Estimate how many more components in network if remove a key broker

Tags: r

In a organizational network I need to remove the broker with the most brokerage power and estimate how many more components the network would have.

Can this be done simply using betweenness centrality? I tried using the brokerage function from the sna package in R, but I keep having difficulties getting it to work properly on my graph.

```
library(intergraph)
library(sna)
net <- intergraph::asNetwork(p_g)
b <- sna::brokerage(net, cl=get.vertex.attribute(net, "name"))$raw.nli[, 't']
max_br <- names(b[b == max(b)])

df <- as_data_frame(p_g) %>%
    .[(.$from != max_br) & (.$to != max_br), ]

g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = F)
igraph::components(g)$no
```

Comment: Please post a small reproducible example, preferably showing some of the code you've tried and any relevant error messages.

Comment: @GregorThomas I added some code. I cannot find the problem myself.